# Opening a new tab for given url in angular 2

Tags: angular

I am working on an angular component. This component displays list of items. Item contains basic information like date, text etc and an url. On clicking text, I need to open a new tab with the url.

I am using this:

```
window.open(url);
```

But I face issue. Suppose current url is www.myapplication.com, and url is www.google.com.
With current implementation, new tab does open but instead of browser url as www.google.com, it is www.myapplication.com/www.google.com.

How to get it working ie opening new tab with www.google.com?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1:**

use http or https before your absolute link. otherwise it will think as a relative link. So, you have to use http or https:

```
window.open(this.url);
```

**Solution 2**

Just use the `<a>` tag and use target attribute and href to the link. and style `<a>` tag as you wish to.

```
<a target="_blank" [href]="link">Google</a>
```

Working solution of both: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-url-to-new-tab)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to put http:/, is the way to specify that a url is absoulte.

it's not a matter of angular, it's just javascript

```
window.open("http://www.google.com");
```